# arrayfire evaluation of equations running really slowly

Tags: gpgpu, arrayfire

I have been working on a project to simulate biologically inspired neural networks using arrayfire. I got to the point of doing some timing tests and was disappointed with the results I was getting. I decided to try and go with one of the fastest, dirt-simple models for a timing test case, the Izhikevich model. When I ran the new test with that model the results were worse. The code I am using is below. It is not doing anything fancy. It is just standard matrix algebra. However, it takes over 5 seconds to do a single evaluation of the equation for just 10 neurons! Every stop after that takes roughly that same amount of time as well.

Code:

```
unsigned int neuron_count = 10;

array a = af::constant(0.02, neuron_count);
array b = af::constant(0.2, neuron_count);
array c = af::constant(-65.0, neuron_count);
array d = af::constant(6, neuron_count);

array v = af::constant(-70.0, neuron_count);
array u = af::constant(-20.0, neuron_count);
array i = af::constant(14, neuron_count);

double tau = 0.2;

void StepIzhikevich()
{
    v = v + tau*(0.04*pow(v, 2) + 5 * v + 140 - u + i);
    //af_print(v);
    u = u + tau*a*(b*v - u);
    //Leaving off spike threshold checks for now
}

void TestIzhikevich()
{
    StepIzhikevich();

    timer::start();

    StepIzhikevich();

    printf("elapsed seconds: %g\n", timer::stop());
}
```

Here are the timing results for different numbers of neurons.

results:

```
neurons   seconds
10        5.18275
100       5.27969
1000      5.20637
10000     4.86609
```

Increasing the number of neurons does not appear to have a huge effect. The time goes down a little. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a better way to optimize things with arrayfire to get better results?

When I switched the v equation to use v*v instead pow(v, 2) the time required for a step went down to 3.75762. That is still extremely slow though, so something odd is happening.

[EDIT]
I tried to split the processing up into pieces and found something new. Here is the code I am using now.

Code:

```
unsigned int neuron_count = 10;

array a = af::constant(0.02, neuron_count);
array b = af::constant(0.2, neuron_count);
array c = af::constant(-65.0, neuron_count);
array d = af::constant(6, neuron_count);

array v = af::constant(-70.0, neuron_count);
array u = af::constant(-20.0, neuron_count);
array i = af::constant(14, neuron_count);

array g = af::constant(0.0, neuron_count);

double tau = 0.2;

void StepIzhikevich()
{
    array j = tau*(0.04*pow(v, 2));
    //af_print(j);

    array k = 5 * v + 140 - u + i;
    //af_print(k);

    array l = v + j + k;
    //af_print(l);

    v = l;  //If this line is here time is long on second loop
    //g = l; //If this is here then time is short.

    //u = u + tau*a*(b*v - u);
    //Leaving off spike threshold checks for now
}

void TestIzhikevich()
{
    timer::start();

    StepIzhikevich();

    printf("elapsed seconds: %g\n", timer::stop());

    timer::start();

    StepIzhikevich();

    printf("elapsed seconds: %g\n", timer::stop());
}
```

When I run it without reassigning back to v, or assigning it to a new variable g, then the time for the step on both the first and second run are small

results:

elapsed seconds: 0.0036143

elapsed seconds: 0.00340621

However, when I put v = l; back in, then the first time it runs it is fast, but from then on it is slow.

results:

elapsed seconds: 0.0034497

elapsed seconds: 2.98624

Any ideas on what is causing this?

[EDIT 2]

I still do not know why it is doing this, but I have found a workaround by copying the v array before using it again.

Code:

```
unsigned int neuron_count = 100000;

array v = af::constant(-70.0, neuron_count);
array u = af::constant(-20.0, neuron_count);
array i = af::constant(14, neuron_count);

double tau = 0.2;

void StepIzhikevich()
{
    //array vp = v;
    array vp = v.copy();
    //af_print(vp);

    array j = tau*(0.04*pow(vp, 2));
    //af_print(j);

    array k = 5 * vp + 140 - u + i;
    //af_print(k);

    array l = vp + j + k;
    //af_print(l);

    v = l;  //If this line is here time is long on second loop
}

void TestIzhikevich()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        timer::start();

        StepIzhikevich();

        printf("loop: %d  ", i);
        printf("elapsed seconds: %g\n", timer::stop());

        timer::start();
    }
}
```

Here are the results now. The second time it runs it is a bit slow, but now it is fast after that. Huge improvement over before.

Results: 
loop: 0  elapsed seconds: 0.657355

loop: 1  elapsed seconds: 0.981287

loop: 2  elapsed seconds: 0.000416182

loop: 3  elapsed seconds: 0.000415045

loop: 4  elapsed seconds: 0.000421014

loop: 5  elapsed seconds: 0.000413339

loop: 6  elapsed seconds: 0.00041675

loop: 7  elapsed seconds: 0.000412202

loop: 8  elapsed seconds: 0.000473321

loop: 9  elapsed seconds: 0.000677432

Comment: The times do not look right at all.

Comment: I finally got around to looking at this in some more detail. I split up the calculations and found that when I set the original v array with new values is what is slow. This comment will not let me post new code, so I try and edit the original question.